# Recursively copy files from one directory to another

Tags: command-line, music, transfer, cp, copy

I have all my music in a folder `/media/kalenpw/MyBook/Music/ABunchOfOtherFoldersWithFilesInside`. I want to copy all of the mp3s to `/media/kalenpw/HDD/Music` so I used:

```
cp -R /media/kalenpw/MyBook/Music/*.mp3 /media/kalenpw/HDD/Music
```

however this only copied the mp3s in the root music folder and did not open any of the artist subdirectories and copy those files.

I was under the impression `-R` would recursively copy all the files. How can I achieve said goal?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use:

```
find /media/kalenpw/MyBook/Music/ -name '*.mp3' -exec cp {} /media/kalenpw/HDD/Music \;
```

---

The reason for your command not working is that names containing wildcards (`*.mp3`) are expanded before the command is run, so if you had three files (`01.mp3`,  `02.mp3`, `03.mp3`) your effective command was:

```
cp -R /media/kalenpw/MyBook/Music/01.mp3 /media/kalenpw/MyBook/Music/02.mp3 /media/kalenpw/MyBook/Music/03.mp3 /media/kalenpw/HDD/Music
```

As you can see `-R` has no effect in this case.

Comment: I recommend `-iname` instead of `-name` in case any files end in `.MP3`.

Comment: Thank you this worked. Or at least is in the process of working.

Answer (score 6):

You have specifically mentioned the files(s)/directory(ies) to be copied as using `*.mp3` i.e. any file/directory name ending in `.mp3`.

So any file ending in `.mp3` in `/media/kalenpw/MyBook/Music/` directory and similarly, any directory ending in `.mp3` in `/media/kalenpw/MyBook/Music/` will be copied, recursively. If there is no such matched file/directory, nothing will be copied.

Now to copy all `.mp3` files from `/media/kalenpw/MyBook/Music/` recursivley to directory `/media/kalenpw/HDD/Music/`:

- Using `bash`:

  ```
  shopt -s globstar
  cp -at /media/kalenpw/HDD/Music /media/kalenpw/MyBook/Music/**/*.mp3
  ```
- Using `find`:

  ```
  find /media/kalenpw/MyBook/Music -type f -name '*.mp3' -exec cp -at /media/kalenpw/HDD/Music {} +
  ```

Comment: Thanks, techraf answered first so I accepted their answer, however.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to do this would be to use a copy command with no wildcards and only directory names:

```
cd /media/kalenpw/HDD
cp -r /media/kalenpw/MyBook/Music .
```

If the current directory didn't already have a directory named Music, this would create a new Music directory in the current directory. If you already have a directory named Music, It would copy the contents of it to the existing Music directory. This, of course, would get all the files, not just the .mp3 files, so it might not give you the flexibility you need.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that you have a bunch of `.docx`, `.mp3`, `.txt` and `.xlsx` files stored in this directory structure:

```
/files/
/files/dir1/
/files/dir1/dir11/
/files/dir1/dir12/
/files/dir1/dir13/
/files/dir2/
/files/dir3/
/files/dir3/dir31/
/files/dir3/dir32/
/files/dir4/
/files/dir5/
/files/dir51/
/files/dir52/
/files/dir53/
/files/dir54/
```

...and you want to recurse into all such directories in order to copy all found `.mp3` files to `/home/me/music/` but you do **not** want to preserve such directory tree in the destination (i.e. you want all found `.mp3` files to be copied to `/home/me/music/` instead of copied to respective directories such as `/home/me/music/dir1/`, `/home/me/music/dir1/dir11/` et cetera).

In such case, at the shell terminal (bash) first run this command in order to access the root of your file search:

```
cd /files
```

...and then run this command:

```
for i in `find . -iname '*.mp3'`; do cp $i /home/me/music/; done
```

In case you **do** want to preserve the source's directory tree in the destination, run this command instead (after running `cd /files`):

```
find . -iname '*.mp3' | cpio -pdm /home/me/music/
```

On the above commands, the search is case-insensitive (i.e. matches `.mp3`, `.MP3`, `.mP3` and `.Mp3`). Use `-name` instead of `-iname` if you want the search to be case-sensitive (e.g. using `-name` for the `.mp3` string of characters will match files ending with `.mp3` but not those ending with `.MP3`, `.mP3` nor `.Mp3`).

It's also important to point out that, in the case of the command that preserves the source directory tree/structure, those folders whose content doesn't match the search criteria won't be copied to the destination. Hence, if e.g. no `.mp3` file is found in `/files/dir5/`, then no `/home/me/music/dir5` directory will be created, but if at least one `.mp3` file is found in `/files/dir5/`, then `/home/me/music/dir5` will be created so such `.mp3` file(s) can be stored inside of it.

Comment: For the case where you *want* to preserve the directory structure, run this command from the source directory. If you run ```find /source/dir -iname '*.mp3' | cpio -pdm /home/me/music/```, it will create /home/me/music/source/dir and the files would be copied to this new location.

Comment: @GautamSreekumar The command `find /source/dir -iname '*.mp3' | cpio -pdm /home/me/music/` creates a copy of the (preserved) directory sctructure in `/home/me/music/source/dir` instead of in `/home/me/music`. In order to prevent this from happening, you need to use `find .` instead of `find /source/dir`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [cpr](https://github.com/circulosmeos/cpr):

```
$ cd /media/kalenpw/HDD/Music
$ cpr -p '/\.mp3$/' '/media/kalenpw/MyBook/Music/'
```

Note that without `-p` [cpr](https://github.com/circulosmeos/cpr) will preserve complete directory paths on copied filenames.
`-r` can be used (instead of `-p`) to preserve the path under '/media.../Music/'.
Also `cpr` will take care that no file is overwritten, appending a number starting at '0001' to any repeated filename copied.