# Copy MP4 files from direcotry tree (-R) to a single directory

Tags: files, copy

I have a bunch of MP4 videos in a directory tree (by category), and I want to recursively copy them all to a single directory on another drive.  I tried:

```
cp -R -p -f /hdd1mnt/Videos/*.mp4 /hdd2mnt/
```

But it just copies the few files in the /hddname/Videos/ directory and doesn't copy any of them from sub-directories under that.  I've tried a few variations, but they all give the same result- no recursion.  Please steer me right!

Thanks,
Bill

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recursively copy files from one directory to another](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802238/recursively-copy-files-from-one-directory-to-another)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using The** `find` **Command**

`find`: Search for files in a directory hierarchy

**Generic**:

```
find [sourcePath] -name ‘[filename]’ -exec cp {} [targetPath] \;
```

**Your Example**:

```
find /hdd1mnt/Videos/ -name '*.mp4' -exec cp {} /hdd2mnt/ \;
```

Replace `-name` with `-iname` to ignore case.

Comment: THANK YOU!  That does it perfectly.  I'm going to put this in my web pages for future reference.